# Objective-C Passing Messages with Arguments in performSelectorOnMainThread:

Tags: objective-c, ios5, objective-c-blocks, performselector

Need help with the syntax when the method being passed into @selector has arguments. Thanks!

```
//This works
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{ 

 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hydrateList) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];   

});



//But what about when the method in the selector has arguments?
//This is incorrect, syntactically
  dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{ 

     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hydrateListForCategory:self.categorySelected) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
  });
```

Comment: Search for that method and read the documentation. [NSObject documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hydrateListForCategory:) withObject:self.categorySelected waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

Hint: that's why the "withObject:" part is there.

Hint 2: Apple has pretty good docs for their frameworks.

Hint 3:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hydrateListForCategory:) withObject:self.categorySelected waitUntilDone:YES];
```